# Upgrading Sitecore 8.0 to 8.1 issue (Session state in web config)

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, sitecore, session-state

I have successfully upgraded Sitecore 8.0 rev. 150812 to Sitecore 8.1.
But when I deployed my project, it stopped work. I have found following error message in Windows event viewer:
"Could not load type 'Sitecore.SessionManagement.ConditionalSessionIdManager. (C:...\Website\web.config line 191)"

That's session state node from web.config file:

> "sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" sessionIDManagerType="Sitecore.SessionManagement.ConditionalSessionIdManager""

I have noted this node was changed due Sitecore upgrading. The previous version is:

> "sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" sessionIDManagerType="Sitecore.**FXM**.SessionManagement.ConditionalSessionIdManager""

(FXM is added)

It looks like my deployment have changed some important dll, but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sitecore 8.1 `ConditionalSessionIdManager` is in `Sitecore.Kernal.dll`.

And it used to be in `Sitecore.FXM.dll` in Sitecore 8.0.

What is the version of `Sitecore.Kernel.dll` in the environment to which you did the deploy?

Does is say `Product version: 8.1.0 rev...`?

It looks like your deployment process copied `Sitecore.Kernel.dll` (and possibly some other Sitecore libraries) from the old Sitecore version.

Comment: this really should be a comment.

Comment: @DanielA.White answer updated. From what is described in the question, I'm pretty sure that's the problem and my post answers it.

Comment: @MarekMusielak, you are right. Current version of `Sitecore.Kernel.dll` is `8.0 ...`. Thanks.